# Query specific fields of mongoDB using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the code below the query gives me all the fields. I only want to query _id and serialno. How to go about it.

Schema

```
var DataSchema = new Schema({
  serialno: String,
  info: String,
  active: Boolean,
  content: String
});
```

Query

```
// Get list of datas
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  Data.find(function (err, data) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(200, data);
  });
};
```

Comment: dataModel.find({ _id : 123456 }, { serialno : 1 })

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are using latest nodejs mongodb driver 3.0 or above try this code:

```
Data.find({}).project({ _id : 1, serialno : 1 }).toArray()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. None of the other answers work properly.

Comment: Yup! This is it! This is the one!

Comment: `.findOne(...).project is not a function`. Bad answer.

Comment: @Yeats they are doing a `find` not a `findOne`

Answer (score 9):

To query and return only specific fields, this is the correct request :

```
Data.find({}, { _id : 1, serialno : 1 }, function (err, data) {
  if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
  return res.json(200, data);
});
```

The second object params is the projection params, in this object, you can set fields to return or hide.

More informations here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: solves my problem. Will mark is as the correct answer.

Comment: This will return all fields. Bad answer.

Answer (score 3):

In MongoDB Node.js Driver v3.1 and above:

```
Collection.find({}, {
   projection: {
     _id: false,
     someField: true
   }
});
```

Second argument to the find/findOne function is `options`. It supports limit, sort, projection, and many more filters.

Source: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOne

Comment: Haha mongodb is really all over the place with their stupid changes. This is not even in their official documentation. And it doesn't make sense. Projection? Really?

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html), you are using the function `collection.find(query[[[, fields], options], callback]);`

So you need to specify the `fields` argument:

```
Data.find(null, { "_id": true, "serialno": true }, function (err, data) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.json(200, data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Below code

```
enter code here`collection.find({}, { projection: {_id:1, serialno: 1}}
```