# Query Specific Fields of MongoDB from Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to query a MongoDB for some specific fields from express.js. I have tried several approaches, but without success, including the suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669849/query-specific-fields-of-mongodb-using-node-js). I have indeed tried as examples the following (and a few more variations):

```
 db.collection("Items").find({}, { Name : 1, Price : 1 }, (err, result) => {
  if (result) {
    console.log(result)
  }
 })
```

Or

```
 db.collection("Items").aggregate( { $project : { Name : 1, Price : 1 } }, (err, result) => {
  if (result) {
   console.log(result)
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you using mongoose or the official node.js driver?

Comment: Thank you Montgomery Watts. I am using the node.js driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo Call does not remove parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64627725/mongo-call-does-not-remove-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
 db.collection("Items").find({}, { projection: { Name : 1, Price : 1 } }).toArray( (err, result) => {
   if (result) {
   console.log(result)
   }
 })
```

J